# Custom Notification Sounds in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, notifications

I'm trying to find out the correct way to handle notifications from firebase with custom sounds in Flutter. Does anyone have some working code for both Android and iOS that they're willing to share?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)